# Apache Poi Chart custom Data Labels

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a XDDFScatterChart with series and data points and created data labels for some data series. I found that i can use standard labels consisting of x and y coordinates and series name. Now I want to set a custom text as a label for single elements of a series but i don't know how to do this.
What i want is something like this:

```
dataLabel.setText("my text");
```

I found some methods around creating data labels but i can't figure out how to set a custom text to any data label.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that currently there is no solution for my problem. Custom Data labels can be done by Excel itself but only with newer versions of the ooxml standard. So the POI ooxml library is the problem in this case. A never version of this should fix the problem but it seems that not many people need this. Maybe newer versions of Apache POI can help.
I will solve my problem by using python xlsxwriter instead of java apache poi to get what i need to do.
If anyone has still an idea how to do the job with java please share it it that would help me a lot.

Comment: *"Custom Data labels can be done by Excel itself but only with newer versions of the ooxml standard"*. Just for information, there is a form of custom labels that is only defined in the newer OOXML standards but it is still possible to set custom labels individually using Excel 2007 and the original XLSX specification. That is what XlsxWriter does. That probably doesn't help you with POI though.